# Can we define a private IBOutlet?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

Does iOS allow developer define a private IBOutlet. For example, there are several buttons in a viewController, and I want to do something with these buttons both in Interface builder and code. However I do not want other class access these buttons. Can I define some "private" IBOutlets for this buttons

example code:

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController<
{
@private:  
    UIButton *o_Button1;
    UIButton *o_Button2;
}

//Can I have these outlets as private???
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *Button1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *Button2;

@end
```

===============================================================

Just get one solution. Wish it will help you.

Combine Abizern and JustSid ideas together, I have a solution like this.

in .h file

```
    @interface myViewController : UIViewController
    {
    @private
         IBOutlet UIButton *Button1;
         IBOutlet UIButton *Button2;
    }

    @end
```

and in .m file

```
    @interface MyViewController ()

    @property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *Button1;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *Button2;

    @end  
    ...
    @synthesize Button1, Button2;
```

Thanks for help from Abizern and JustSid

Comment: I guess if you dont set the `@property` and `@synthesize` for the objects, it cannot be accessed outside the class...

Comment: Not working! My code: https://notepad.pw/4vmcjyr1. I am using storyboard. When I subclass this view controller class and use it. It changes both property's values from xib. :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the properties in a category at the top of the .m file:

```
@interface MyViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *Button1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *Button2;

@end
```

In fact, this is how you can set up a property as readonly in the .h file and redeclare it as a readwrite property in the .m file - so you can have private setters.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't this give you a warning in Interface Builder (or the NIB editor in Xcode 4) since it only looks in the .h file for declared IBOutlets?

Comment: A bit of advice, don't bother making your properties/methods private unless you're developing an open source framework/class, it makes testing/refactoring/development needlessly difficult.

Comment: Daniel is right. I can not found Button's outlet in Interface builder.

Comment: Well, yeah. That's what it means to be `private` - it restricts visibility outside the class. But - a)you asked the question and I answered :) b)The trick I mentioned to make a property readonly publicly and readwrite internally is useful to know and c)Properties aren't really private, just as methods aren't really private. You can call `setObject:forKey:` on a property, and although the compiler will complain, the runtime will let you call even private setters.

Comment: Thanks Abizern, it give me great help. I have combine your solution with JustSid's. and post it below your answer by mistake. I can not remove it, so just let it be. wish it can help others

Comment: There's really no reason to use `@property` for an `IBOutlet`.  Just make them a private ivar.  `@property` is for things that you *want* to be publicly accessible.  Trying to make a "private" one is subversive, at best.

Comment: @aroth Not really - If you are using Xcode 4+ you can control drag from the storyboard or the xib file into the class extension section of the .m file to create and hook up these properties.

Comment: Not working! My code: notepad.pw/4vmcjyr1. I am using storyboard. When I subclass this view controller class and use it. It changes both property's values from xib. :(

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer above has the problem that IB won't be able to see the outlets.

The approach I use is to create a file called MyViewController-Protected.h and place the category with the private IBOutlets there. In your MyViewController.m you include the -Protected.h instead of the regular one.

The protected file could look like this:

```
// MyViewController-Protected.h
// Protected extensions to MyViewController

#import "MyViewController.h"

@interface MyViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *Button1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *Button2;

@end
```

IBOutlets defined this way are only visible to classes including the Protected header file. This is only the class itself usually.

Once the category is in a protected header file, Interface Builder will be able to find the outlets. (For XCode3, you have to drag your -Protected.h file to IB, in Xcode4 it will work out of the box).

Answer (score 4):

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController
{
@private
    IBOutlet UIButton *o_Button1;
    IBOutlet UIButton *o_Button2;
}

@end
```

This code allows you to have the outlet without a property that others might access.

Comment: Thanks JustSid, it give me great help. I have combine your solution with Abizern's. and post it under Abizern's answer.